# Ommit empty <> in C++ templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

Is there a way to omit an empty `<>` in C++11 to make the syntax nicer, meaning writing `Foo` instead of `Foo<>` for a template class.

It is clear to me that I can rename/namespace etc. the class. But I want to optimize away two characters not confuse the user with a new name or forcing him to type much more than before.

Full example:

```
template<int N = 1>
class Foo{};

using Foo = Foo<>;
int main()
{
  Foo foo; // I want to be able to write this.
  Foo<> foo; // Works but is ugly.
}
```

Comment: Sure, use a `typedef`. The STL does this, e.g. a `std::string` is a typedef of a template type (namely `std::basic_string<...>`).

Comment: Can you put the template `Foo` into its own namespace [like so](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1sgB7u2Uy2TV4nwR)?

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yes, but this does not make the developers life easier if he want to use the templated version.

Comment: @AndreasPasternak How about a local `using` [like so](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JOpdhbJQDjvlnlbJ)?

Comment: BTW in C++17 you can just leave out the template argument, because defaulted template arguments can always be deduced as part of the new [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (sometimes referred to as “deduction guides”).

Comment: @HenriMenke: Yep, but I am stuck with C++11/14. :(

Comment: As far as I'm concerned the `<>` is a useful reminder that you're dealing with a template. C++ didn't get where it is by caring about syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Havenard That has changed with the newer standards (from C++11 on) Focus is now on usability and simplicity

Comment: It is possible. This is called moving with the time. Use c++17. Huge efforts are done to make each standard retro compatible. Also compilers avoid most of the regressions, and new versions fix bugs that are certainly causing organic errors right now in your code base. So there are no reason on earth to continue to compile with an older standard or with an old compiler. If the compiler does not move, just change of vendor. If this decision is not yours, so change of company. I mean there are no reason to excavate coal with the hand today. You are in a such situation.

Answer (score 1):

You only have one option to make this syntax work and that is switching to **C++17**.  Then you can just leave out the template argument, because defaulted template arguments can always be deduced as part of the new [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) (sometimes referred to as “deduction guides”).

```
template<int N = 1>
class Foo{};

int main() {
    { Foo foo; }
    { Foo<> foo; }
}
```

[Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/B4uwemyCV0OfsH8c)

---

Depending on what tradeoffs you can make, there are two solutions which work with **C++11**.

1. Using a different name for the alias template.

   ```
   template<int N = 1>
   class Foo{};

   using FooNoArgs = Foo<>;

   int main() {
       { FooNoArgs foo; }
       { Foo<> foo; }
   }
   ```

   [Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fghx4UXJhhle5pOo)
2. Moving the template to its own namespace combined with a local `using` if you need to access the templated variant.

   ```
   namespace foo {
   template<int N = 1>
   class Foo{};
   }

   using Foo = foo::Foo<>;

   int main() {
       { Foo foo; }
       { using foo::Foo; Foo<> foo; }
   }
   ```

   [Live on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qPuv6NsfDUZEfVXF)